# How do I use my dataset in Sklearn clustering?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to adapt the Sklearn example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html) to use my own dataset, which is a 1000 row, 4 column matrix of integers. I cannot see how to replace one of the SKlearn datasets with mine. I.e. what do I replace

```
noisy_circles = datasets.make_circles(n_samples=n_samples, factor=.5,
                                  noise=.05)
```

with?

Answer (score 0):

The `datasets.make_circles` function creates a [toy dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_circles.html#sklearn.datasets.make_circles) with a very clear pattern. The data it returns is a tuple containing an X array of features (n x 2 dimensions) and a y array of labels (length n).

To pass your data into the clustering script, you just need to put it into a similar format and use that in place of the value returned by `make_circles`.

Answer (score 0):

Load your data as a 2 dimensional numpy array. Read the documentation of numpy and scipy to learn how to do so depending on the file format you have at hand.

Before running the clustering algorithm you might want to preprocess the data with a [one-hot encoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features) if the integer mean category assignment rather than quantities.

If they represent quantities, you might want to preprocess with [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling).